# Are questions specific to sailing on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I encountered this question just now:

[What's the hardest wearing multibraid rope type?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/18222/3076)

and I wonder about a comment that was made on that question:

> yes sailors or boaters have attempted many many times to get a boating specific stack exchange site off the ground but unfortunately couldn't get past the activity levels required – barrymac Jan 25 '18 at 17:11

I realize sailing is definitely an outdoor activity, even if it is not what one immediately pictures when seeing the word "outdoors". However, given the absence of a proper sailing SE, would TGO.SE work in lieu of such?

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh, thanks for the link